# Java: Integer division round up

Tags: java, int, percentage

I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter the total amount of floors in a hotel, the number of rooms in each floor, and the number of occupied rooms. In the end it should display the total # of rooms, the total # of rooms occupied, and the percentage of the rooms occupied. I am having problems with displaying the percentage of rooms occupied. I'm using all int numbers.

This is the equation that I put:

```
roomsOccPercentage = (totalRoomsOccupied * 100) / totalRooms ;
```

When I submit the program into my professor's Java runner it displays:

```
65 % of the Rooms are occupied.
```

But the one my professor provided outputted the answer 66 % instead so the program won't accept my file.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is it a DecimalFormat error?

Edit: Here is the whole code

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class hw7_1 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0");
        int totalFloors;
        int totalRooms = 0;
        int numFloors;
        int numRooms;
        int roomsOccupied;
        int totalRoomsOccupied = 0;
        int roomsOccPercentage = 0;

        //prompting users to input # of floors, no inputs below 1 floor
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of floors in the hotel: ");
            numFloors = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (numFloors < 1) {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of floors. ");
            }
        }
        while (numFloors < 1);

        //for loops on how many rooms on each hotel floors
        for ( int Floors = 1; Floors <= numFloors; Floors++) {
            if (Floors == 13 ) {
                continue;
            }

            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: " + Floors );
                numRooms = keyboard.nextInt();

                if (numRooms < 10) {
                    System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of rooms. ");
                }
            } while (numRooms < 10);

            System.out.println("Please enter the number of occupied rooms on floor #: " + Floors);
            roomsOccupied = keyboard.nextInt();

            totalRooms = totalRooms + numRooms;
            totalRoomsOccupied = totalRoomsOccupied + roomsOccupied;
            roomsOccPercentage = (totalRoomsOccupied * 100) / totalRooms ;
        }
        System.out.println("\nThe hotel has a total of " + totalRooms + " rooms.");
        System.out.println(totalRoomsOccupied + " of the rooms are occupied.");
        System.out.println(formatter.format(roomsOccPercentage) + "% of the rooms are occupied.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It could most likely be the case. You could try to cast any 1 of the operands so that it'd no longer be an integer division. `roomsOccPercentage = ((float)totalRoomsOccupied * 100) / totalRooms;`

Comment: @R.J's comment should solve your problem.

Comment: The thing is we haven't learn that method in class yet. Is there a more beginner's way?

Comment: @SamYoung - You've not used the `double` or `float` data type yet?

Comment: @R.J we have. I meant we don't usually used the casting operator on our calculations yet. I only know of it from reading up on programming. The Math.ceil seemed to have worked but THAT we haven't gone over in class yet at all. Thank you!

Comment: @SamYoung - You could atleast have the `roomsOccPercentage` which actually represents some percentage as a `double`. You're anyways using a decimal formatter to format the output decimal value, so better use it on a decimal which actually has the decimal point.

Comment: And regarding the cast, if you can't do that, you could try something like this. `roomsOccPercentage = (totalRoomsOccupied * 100.0) / totalRooms;`. This would work as well.

Comment: @R.J this worked perfectly! Thanks! What is the logic behind the extra .0?

Comment: @SamYoung - I made it an answer and responded to your query there! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make your `roomsOccPercentage` a double first.

```
double roomsOccPercentage = 0.0;
```

and then cast either of the operands so avoid an integer division.

```
roomsOccPercentage = (totalRoomsOccupied * 100.0) / totalRooms;
```

You can either use an explicit cast like `(double)totalRoomsOccupied` or just make `100` as `100.0` which is a floating point number, thus making the division too, a floating point one and not an integer division.

Answer (score 20):

Note that java plays with its own rule, You need to obey them. Decide if you want floor or ceil of the result, Follow example given below.

```
double roomsOccPercentage;
roomsOccPercentage =Math.ceil((double)5/4); //will be 2
roomsOccPercentage =Math.ceil(5/4); //will be 1
roomsOccPercentage =Math.floor((double)5/4); //will be 1
```

I hope you can now find java intresting

Comment: thank you. Yes I have searched up on that method. It's just that my class hasn't gone over it yet so I am very reluctant to use it. I'm just trying to figure out if I missed anything else.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer to go into doubles to make an integer division that rounds up, you can do that. If you prefer not to, you don’t need to, it’s just a very slight bit tricky:

```
private static int divideRoundUp(int denominator, int divisor) {
    return (denominator + divisor - 1) / divisor;
}
```

Let’s try it:

```
    System.out.println(divideRoundUp(196, 3));
    System.out.println(divideRoundUp(197, 3));
    System.out.println(divideRoundUp(118, 2));
    System.out.println(divideRoundUp(119, 2));
```

This prints:

```
66
66
59
60
```

If there’s no remainder, as in 118 / 2, you get the normal result. In other cases the result is rounded up. How to handle negative denominator and/or divisor is left as an exercise for the reader, though.

In school many of us learned that 65.5 and higher should be rounded up to 66, where as numbers between 65.0 and 65.5 should be rounded down to 65. If you want this, the method is a bit different:

```
private static int divideRoundHalfUp(int denominator, int divisor) {
    return (denominator + divisor / 2) / divisor;
}
```

Demonstration:

```
    System.out.println(divideRoundHalfUp(196, 3));
    System.out.println(divideRoundHalfUp(197, 3));
    System.out.println(divideRoundHalfUp(118, 2));
    System.out.println(divideRoundHalfUp(119, 2));
```

Output:

```
65
66
59
60
```

Answer (score 1):

`a / b + a % b / (b/2)` ??
1 divide by 3 should be 0
`1 / 3 + 1 % 3 / (3/2) = 0 + 1 / 1 = 1` which is NOT 0

I recommend this:

```
(a + a % b) / b
```

Comment: If a = 4, b = 3, (a + a % b) / b = 1

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simple way to round up:

```
double dnum; = 47.213; //make this your value to round up
int inum; //null for now, will be your rounded up integer
if(dnum > (int)num)
     inum = (int)(num + 1.0);
else
     inum = (int)num;
```

If its not already an integer, it adds one and casts it down. If it is an integer, it casts it as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Given `a/b`, if you want it to round to the nearest integer, you need to add 1 if the remainder is half or more than half of b, therefore:

```
a / b + a % b / (b/2)
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: perhaps `a / b + (a % b) * 2 / b`, as that way you do not lose precision in the integer division by 2